# useMeetingManager must be used within MeetingProvider

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-chime

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWX0m.png)I am integrated amazon chime with react.js by this link https://aws.github.io/amazon-chime-sdk-component-library-react/?path=/docs/sdk-components-introduction--page but I got an Error
"useMeetingManager must be used within MeetingProvider"
how can I resolve it

Answer (score 0):

For example, in this demo the App.js file contains the MeetingProvider: https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-chime-media-capture-pipeline-demo/blob/main/site/src/App.js

```js
<ThemeProvider theme={lightTheme}>
  <MeetingProvider>
    <Meetings />
  </MeetingProvider>
</ThemeProvider>
```

Then, in the Meetings.js file:
https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-chime-media-capture-pipeline-demo/blob/main/site/src/Meeting.js

```js
export const Meetings = () => {
    const meetingManager = useMeetingManager();

...
     await meetingManager.join(meetingSessionConfiguration, options);
     await meetingManager.start();
     meetingManager.invokeDeviceProvider(DeviceLabels.AudioAndVideo);
```

https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-chime-media-capture-pipeline-demo/blob/a83f7c7186e6cca39dff8eba1fb46ca8b9c24914/site/src/Meeting.js#L106-L129